# Realm notificationToken modifications in sectioned tableview

Tags: swift, realm

Say you have a `UITableview` with multiple sections. And a realm notificationToken that subscribes to updates on either a `List<Object>` with filtering or a separate `List<Object>` for each section. (Or `Result<Object>`, whatever)

How do you update with modifications (`insertRows()/deleteRow()/reloadRows()`) instead of `reloadData()` on whole thing? `tableView.endUpdates()` raises an exception when a section notification update is triggered, and another section has (relatively) simultaneously changed.

This is a pretty common setup and haven't found an elegant solution (yet).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have Realm notifications automatically handle grouping of table rows into sections. There's [an issue on the Realm Cocoa GitHub tracking this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3384).

At present, the easiest way to go about this would be to either have a single notification block and work out the section logic yourself, or have a separate notification block for each section.

Additionally, while slightly older than Realm notifications and not officially supported, there's also [this third party library that can support that kind of functionality](https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController).